# Salesforce stuck in Organization Administration Locked state after using Apex Test Execution

Tags: salesforce

I used the **Apex Test Execution** screen to run all the test cases in a sandbox org.

Several of the test cases passed and then progress appeared to hang on one test case which was previously working.

I then used the Abort button to try and cancel the test execution which appeared to work.

Now any subsequent attempts to run tests never progress past the Queued state.

[image: ApexTestQueueItem stuck in Queued State]

Selecting an individual apex class and using the synchronous **Run Test** button results in the following error message:

> **Organization Administration Locked**
>
> The changes you requested require
> salesforce.com to temporarily lock your organization's administration
> setup. However, the administration setup has already been locked by
> another change. Please wait for the previous action to finish, then
> try again later.

Trying to save changes to an Apex Class from Eclipse gives the error:

> - Save error: Unable to perform save on all files: The changes you requested require > salesforce.com to temporarily lock your organization's administration setup. However, the
>   administration setup has already been locked by another change. Please wait for > the previous action to finish, then try again later. (ALREADY_IN_PROCESS)

If I query the ApexTestQueueItem table there appear to be 3 test cases stuck with the Processing status.

[image: ApexTestQueueItem stuck in Processing]

**How can I clear out these ApexTestQueueItems from the Processing state?** I'm assuming that this will get me past the Organization Administration lock.

I did check the Setup Audit Trail and the only recent changes were from my user to Apex Classes.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue right now. At first I thought its my code but after seeing this I am sure its something wrong with Salesforce

Comment: @manubkk, While I am glad to hear it isn't just me with the issue it isn't a great place to be in as it stops any further development work in that org.

I did find a similar question in the developer force forum - [Run All Tests and Network/Proxy Settings](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Run-All-Tests-and-Network-Proxy-Settings/m-p/405835)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, for almost 12 hours now, logged Case # 07112508. Lost an entire development day. I'm really hoping I don't loose tomorrow too.

Comment: Same here, all I could do was save my uncompiled code locally and wait until the org got unlocked to compile them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated**

My support case got escalated to the "Senior Support Team". They did something to my sandbox and advised that it is a known issue and to only run test cases for one class at a time via the Apex Class UI (E.g. https://xyz.salesforce.com/01pL00000000001).

I should **not** run the test cases via:

- The Apex Test Execution UI
- Manually creating ApexTestQueueItem records
- Apex Classes - [Run All Tests]

I'm assuming that Eclipse is OK at the moment for individual test cases as it isn't async in nature.

I'd like to be able to tell you what exactly they did to my problem sandbox orgs but I'm not sure at the moment. Hopefully a parallel question on the developerforce forum will produce some answers - [Using Apex Test Execution results in a "Organization Administration Locked" that doesn't clear](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Announcements/Using-Apex-Test-Execution-results-in-a-quot-Organization/td-p/406513)

Some interesting info from Twitter:

["...been working on it all day. Hope to have the fix out next wk." - Rich Unger](https://twitter.com/#!/rich_unger/status/175060451347021824)

["@rich_unger great to hear, thanks for update, any short term workaround? if not, I'll move my code to another org until then" - Michael Gallagher. "@mjgallag24 workaround is to not use async testing" - Rich Unger](https://twitter.com/#!/rich_unger/status/175064147938115585)

So to answer my own question of **"How can I clear out these ApexTestQueueItems from the Processing state?"**

Answer: You can't currently if you are experiencing the "known issue". The only option is to raise a support case and wait for Salesforce to clear it.

---

I've tried the following anonymous apex to clear the apex test cases out of the processing queue:

```
List<ApexTestQueueItem> items = [Select Id,ApexClassId,Status,ExtendedStatus,ParentJobId from ApexTestQueueItem where Status != 'Completed'];
for(ApexTestQueueItem atqi : items) {
    atqi.Status = 'ABORTED';
}
update items;
```

This doesn't seem to have the desired result as on a subsequent SOQL query to ApexTestQueueItem the Status column remains unchanged.

I went looking for the Apex job under [Administration Setup > Monitoring > Apex Jobs] but none of the records where JobType=TestRequest appeared.

Next I tried aborting the job using anonymous apex:

```
System.abortJob('707L0000000FgZIIA0');
```

The AsyncApexJob changed Status to 'Aborted'.

Comment: I ran the System.abortJob to set the AsyncApexJob status to 'Aborted' and was also able to set the ApexTestQueueItem status to 'ABORTED' but the Administration is still locked

Comment: No, System.abortJob didn't work. The status changed to aborted but the Org Admin lock remained. I suspect this is something that only Salesforce support can resolve.

Comment: I aborted AsyncApexJob first, but ApexTestQueueItem records were still showing Queued. I used the script you mentioned to update the status. It WORKED!

Answer (score 1):

In one of my orgs it's unlocked after around 16 hours, I was able to avoid getting it locked again by running my test classes one at a time, but not through the Apex Text Execution page, I am either doing did it through the IDE or Apex Class Page in the UI

Answer (score 0):

You should really file a case for this. Without knowing more information, like your org id, we can't tell what's really going on. The short term solution will probably involve us killing the zombie Processing tests on our end.

Rich Unger
Apex Code Team

Comment: Thanks, I've logged a support case (07109567) but I'm not sure if it will still be an issue within the response time of 2 business days.

Comment: I've managed to phone through Basic and then Premier Support who escalated the case up to tier 2 support. Sounds like they are getting closer to resolving it. I'd like to find the cause or a quick way of resolving this as I've lost 6+ hours of not being able to modify apex classes or run test cases.

Answer (score 0):

We were told by SF Support that it is a known issue, a fix is in the pipeline and they hope to roll it out next Wednesday

Comment: Thanks, do you have a case # I can refer to? I'm waiting for a call back from a Developer Support Engineer and if I can point them to a similar case it might save some time.

Comment: Almost a year later and I'm having the exact same issue right now, luckily it's Friday and I can go home and let the problem fix itself over the weekend (has usually taken around 12h for it to disappear before). As usual, I think SF Support said something to make you stop complaining so they could close the case without actually fixing anything.